# Do I need a wildcard cert if I'm running two SSL websites off different ports?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate, virtualhost

If I've got two vhosts for two different websites running off 8081 and 8082 (both SSL), do I need a wildcard cert? The hostnames resolve to the same IP but seeing as they are running off of different ports can I serve the correct cert? They are behind a reverse proxy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, the port of your webserver is not relevant for SSL, only the hostname matters.

Thus: https://www.example.com:8443 and https://www.example.com:8444

can use the same SSL-Cert with e.g. `CN=www.example.com`

Your last sentence makes me wonder though: *...behind a reverse proxy...*
From where to where do you want to have your SSL-Connections? 
From the internet to the proxy (both ports) or from the proxy to the backend servers (different ports)?